# Intellij IDEA + Groovy + better static validation?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I have a method in a Grails service:

```
void methodA(Car car) { }
```

and a second method in the same class calling this method:

```
void methodB() { 
    methodA("A string")

}
```

But intellij doesnt even warn for this clearly incorrect usage.

I understand that a methodA can be injected with a String signature, but is there a way to make Intellij act or expect less dynamic behavior?

It would be nice to code statically with Groovy yet continue to have some kind of flag.

It would be a real downer if one has to choose so drastically between Java and Groovy.

I am using Grails 2.3.7, and I believe it is using Groovy 2.x.y

Comment: I don't use Intellij but have you looked at using @CompileStatic in Groovy 2.x?

Comment: Great! Is there a way to declare this globally somehow, or do I need to do this per class basis? Is is possible to do from one root config files in Grails?

Comment: No there isn't a flag for that in Grails because portions of the framework itself can't be compiled statically. It's up to you to indicate what is static or not.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Intellij doesnt seem to be reporting the same kind of errors that the compiler does from the command line when running grails run-app... room for improvement...

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ do you use? With latest versions it shows a warning with your particular use case.

Comment: I don't think the `@CompileStatic` flag is a good solution here. It may give you an error but it also 'disables' some(most?) dynamic features of Groovy (and behaves a little different) and thats why you are using groovy in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using IntelliJ `IDEAD 12.1.6` and it does provide a warning for your example:

[image: IdeaWarning]

On the Idea [Groovy Plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Groovy+language+features) page it states the following:

> Inapplicable method calls marked as warnings

Do you have that plugin installed/enabled? (check under file->settings->plugins)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that I had disabled that inspection due to some other incorrect usage. I also now changed it to a red flag. Hopefully it is the only place now, otherwise I guess I have to supress :S